# How to read parquet files using DuckDB in Go?

Tags: go, parquet, duckdb, apache-arrow-flight

I'm building an [Arrow Flight SQL server](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/FlightSql.html) in Go wrapping DuckDB to query a large number of parquet files(each with a different schema). I want those parquet files to be loaded into DuckDB on-demand(i.e. when a query is made over it) instead of loading all those files into DuckDB database at startup.

[DuckDB CLI](https://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.2.9/data/parquet) supports such behaviour by allow SQL queries over a group of files matching a glob pattern which is perfect. However when I start a simple Go Arrow Flight SQL server to connect to DuckDB and pass a single parquet file to use as the data source, I get an error when the server starts up.

Here is a snippet of my test code:

```
func CreateDB() (*sql.DB, error) {
    // Connect to the DuckDB database.
    db, err := sql.Open("duckdb", "parquet:/path/to/local/parquet/file.parquet")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil, err
    }
    defer db.Close()
    fmt.Println("Connection to DuckDB created successfully!")
    return db, nil
}

func main() {
    host := flag.String("host", "localhost", "IP/Hostname to bind the server to")
    port := flag.String("port", "31337", "Port to bind the server to")

    db, err := CreateDB()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    srv := NewDuckDBFlightSQLServer(db)
    server := flight.NewServerWithMiddleware(nil)
    server.RegisterFlightService(flightsql.NewFlightServer(srv))
    server.Init(net.JoinHostPort(*host, *port))
    server.SetShutdownOnSignals(os.Interrupt, os.Kill)

    fmt.Println("DuckDB Flight SQL Server started on ", server.Addr(), "...")

    if err := server.Serve(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

The error seen when running this code is:

```
could not open database: Binder Error: Unrecognized storage type "parquet"
2023/09/12 10:27:13 could not open database: Binder Error: Unrecognized storage type "parquet"
```

Basically it doesn't like `parquet:` prefix in the `sql.Open()` call. Removing that prefix gives a different(and a more obvious) error

```
could not open database: IO Error: The file "/path/to/local/parquet/file.parquet" exists, but it is not a valid DuckDB database file!
```

Connecting to DuckDB with in-memory database(passing second arg of `sql.Open()` as empty string) works fine and the server starts successfully.

Whats the right way to achieve this in Go? I do not find reference implementation(or starter docs) for "DuckDB + parquet + arrowFlightSQL" in Go yet. Does the duckDB driver in Go not support querying parquet files directly?

I've tested this on Go 1.18.10.

Comment: BTW this issue is not related to Arrow Flight SQL at all. Even starting a simple HTTP Go server to connect to DuckDB reading parquet files throws the same error.

Answer (score 2):

First create a database the same way you do for sqlite:

```
db, err := sql.Open("duckdb", "mydb.db")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    return nil, err
}
```

and after that you can load you parquet file this way:

```
_, _ = db.execute("install 'parquet'")
_, _ = db.execute("load 'parquet'")
_, _ = db.execute("create view mydata as select * from read_parquet('path/to/your/parquet/file'")
```

Finally you can query your data this way:

```
_, _ = db.execute("select * from mydata")
```

[See the doc here](https://duckdb.org/docs/archive/0.8.1/data/parquet/overview)

Hope it helps.